# Query to find users with passwords same as their username in Oracle

Tags: oracle, security, audit, password

I'm writing an Oracle audit script where I need to find users in a database who have set their passwords to be the same as their username, e.g. dbaadmin/dbaadmin. The query would need to get the list of users in the database & then check if their passwords is same as their respective usernames.

Can anyone help me out with this query?

PS: I'm a Database newbie.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? The hashing algorithm changed after 10g.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible for current versions of Oracle. What I understand happens is that Oracle generates an instance-specific [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and adds this to the passwords being hashed using the SHA1 algorithm, the result of which is stored as the hashed password. See for example http://marcel.vandewaters.nl/oracle/security/password-hashes for information about this algorithm.

This means that password hashes are installation specific, and I don't think it's possible to generate the expected hash value for a given username/password combination.

What you need to do is as @elfcheg suggests to add a `password_verify_function` on all profiles, or to a single profile, and assign this profile to all users.

Answer (score 1):

What if user has login "SCOTT" and password "ScoTt"? Do you still need to find this one?

I think what you really need is to set password_verify_function in users profile. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/network.1111/e16543/authentication.htm#i1007341 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001097.htm) you can find how to generate the password hash. (This algorithm worked both on version 11.2 and 12.1 when I tried with some simple examples.) The next challenge is - as already mentioned -, to try all possible combinations of lowercase and uppercase letters in a password, if you want to cover everything.

This will not be a single query, but some PL/SQL code that would run for quite a long time depending on the length of the username.

Answer (score 0):

User:  ABC  with password aBc  is not a match!
It is an easy and exploitable password, but no different than abc123 in terms of security, and not the same as the UserID !

ABC and aBc generate a different ASCCI code, different MD5 code etc

To answer the question in context,  there are some "sec_" parameters to assist us in that category.

If the intended question is:  has user SCOTT the password SCOTT then it is much easier to answer for X=Y in this case.
SCOTT != ScoTt   It sure looks like it, but they are different.
Just like SCOTT != $c0T7

There are password strength, and password match criteria.
Ideally, SCOTT should have a password like "My F4v0r173 1c3-KrE4^^ 1s $7rAw*eRrY"
Or a keychain password.
It must be practical and if you lose your keychain, then you should be able  to remember the proper sequence