# Retrieve user password in Oracle

Tags: oracle, password, sysdba

How to obtain the password of a specified user in Oracle? What query to use to obtain that?

Comment: Passwords in all modern versions of Oracle are stored encrypted so there's no point in trying to retrieve them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to find users with passwords same as their username in Oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101713/query-to-find-users-with-passwords-same-as-their-username-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot; Oracle does not store user passwords, only their hash values, which you can retrieve by `select password from dba_users where username = 'WHATEVER'`.

Comment: I think in order to see the full password hash you have to select table `SYS.USER$`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Quite properly, Oracle Database does not store passwords in any recoverable form.

If, like me, you have a need to drop *and recreate* a given account, use:

```
set long 32767 ;
dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'USER', 'account-name' ) user_ddl from dual ;
```